# Can I use material-ui FloatingActionButton as the submit and reset button for my redux-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm attempting a simple redux form using Material UI component. Following the example on their page it's easy to get redux Field components rendering as material-ui fields ?

However I would like to use material-ui buttons as the Submit and Reset buttons for my form rather than just the standard HTML . Despite searching at length and trying a few things I cannot get this to work.

Any idea if it is possible to use material-ui buttons (e.g. FloatingActionButton) as my redux-form buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h6kvv8j0/3/

Just apply the "type" attribute:

```
<form ...>
  <FloatingActionButton type="submit">...</FloatingActionButton>
  <FloatingActionButton type="reset">...</FloatingActionButton>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but your example only works for regular forms and not for a redux-form